# Twig reset of loop.index0

Tags: twig

I have a problem with Twig, my `loop.index0` is reinitializing (at 0), but I do not understand why.

Here is my model:

@DonCallisto : Ok I reduce my code :

```
<table>
    {% for j in 0..1 %}
        <tr {% if loop.first %}class="z-depth-2"{% endif %}>
            {% for i in 0..6 %}
                <td>
                    {% set day = 'now'|date('d') - loop.revindex0 %}
                    {% if loop.parent.loop.index == 1 %} 
                        {{ [day, 9, 'now'|date('Y')]|join('-')|date('l')|trans }} {{ day }}
                    {% else %}
                        {% if "OK" == "OK" %}
                            <a class='dropdown-button  btn green z-depth-1' href='#' data-activates='OK'>OK</a>
                            <ul id='OK' class='dropdown-content'>
                                <li><a href="{{ day }}">Logs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CkSums</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Volumétrie</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                <td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Well I have try to push a good value in the {% if save.displayState == "OK" %} without succes, Idk why, but nothink really work :(

I don't understand why my `Saves[i]['day']` stay stuck on 13 and my `loop.index0` on 0 in my dropdown.

@DarkBee: Thx for this tip

EDIT: I worked with twigfiddle.com (thanks to DarkBee) I reworked my template, but on my project the problem remains the same and on twigfiddle I can not reproduce it ...

Comment: Hi, please try to format the code better in order to avoid as much as possible the horizontal scroll. This way it will be easier to find the problem and help you. Thank you and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Aer you sure this is the full code? Work as is over [here](https://twigfiddle.com/vblscl)

Comment: Hi, I thinking that was enought this code, but you can take all twig files (base>header>index>save>state) on https://spaces.hightail.com/space/c9IFbaELZM

Comment: Even with your full code everything is running fine. See [revision](https://twigfiddle.com/vblscl/2)